# Windows inaccessible after NVMe ssd upgrade, but grub and Linux partition work fine

Tags: linux, windows-10, boot, ssd, grub

I have an Asus ROG Scar II Strix that had the stock 512gb NVMe ssd, which I have upgraded to a Crucial 4TB PCIe 3.0 M.2 ssd. On the original ssd, I five partitions, which I have cloned onto the new drive (grub, system recovery, windows 10 home install, Manjaro Linux install, and a shared data partition so I can blow away either OS without losing my files). I have installed the M.2 drive correctly, verified that the CMOS battery is not the issue, and checked UEFI for any missing paths to the boot file or misconfigurations that I am aware of. I had originally thought I had not flashed it correctly, however after giving uefi a direct path to grub, I found that everything works except windows.

If I try to boot to windows, it goes into the typical system recovery loop and will neither recover nor boot correctly. I have pretty much ruled out all possible hardware issues. How do I recover my windows install? I could blow it away, but I don't have a backup and don't want to spend the next two weeks reinstalling and reconfiguring it. I have tried all of the presented windows repair or recovery options and none of them worked, including trying to reinstall windows from the recovery partition. It is on the new ssd correctly, it just doesn't want to run, and it is only the windows related partitions giving me problems. I have spent a great bit of time already researching answers online, but did not find one that really addressed a multi-boot upgrade scenario. Thanks in advance. I am actually asking from the Manjaro install, so the disk definitely works correctly otherwise.

Comment: Can you boot Windows directly? UEFI > Boot > Select Windows bootloader manager. If the option isn't available or produce the same result you'll have to to boot Windows installation media and repair the Windows boot.

Comment: I cannot. I am currently trying to flash a windows iso to a usb to attempt a recovery that way. I can do this in manjaro despite not having access to the windows side.

Comment: I will also point out that the drive registers in uefi correctly, and it does detect the boot paths automatically. Only windows is grumbling.

Comment: You should configure windows not to restart automatically at the bluescreen so that you can quote it. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/advanced-startup-options-including-safe-mode-b90e7808-80b5-a291-d4b8-1a1af602b617 as recommended there, it can be useful for troubleshooting.

Answer (score -1):

Boot into safe mode. Modern windows will use generic drivers for the hard drive controller in safe mode that are otherwise not tried. When that works, the normal boot will work afterwards, too.

Comment: I had tried that, and it does the same boot loop behavior. I can't rule this out as the answer, but it is possible that windows is overreaching into uefi in some way that is also relevant that has to be resolved first.

Comment: If it winds up being this and some setting, I will accept this answer and comment with the extra step I had to do

Comment: Nope, this misses the point entirely. The symptom is of a bootloader pointing to the wrong location, it happens the same as if the system partition has been deleted. So, again, after confirming the partition still exists - it should if the cloning process was correctly done - all you have to do is to boot Windows installation media and repair the boot. It has absolutely nothing to do with "hard drives" drivers. Actually no HDDs are even involved here.